# knockout js binding limitation on complex view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am 3 months into learning KnockoutJS and it has been great so far. However, I am facing an issue with binding.
This is the scenario:

1. I am using MVC with KO.
2. MVC model is passed down to the view, converted into a knockout object and pushed into the viewModel variable:

   `var data = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
   var viewModel = new HP.ViewModels.CertificationPathViewModel(data);
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`
3. Within viewModel, I reference the MVC model as self.data:

   `ViewModels.CertificationPathViewModel = (function (data) {
       var self = ViewModels.BaseEntityViewModel.apply(this, [data]);
       // some other code
       return { Data: self.Data, }; 
   }`

   `ViewModels.BaseEntityViewModel = (function (data) {
   var self = this;
   self.data = ko.observable(data);
       // other code
        return { Data: self.data, }; 
    }`
4. On the view, I data-bind like this:

   `<div id="drpControl" data-bind="CustomDropdown: Data().BusinessUnits.SelectedGroup, optionSettings: { CustomOptions: Data().Units.Groups, CustomOptionsCaption: '-- Select Group --' }"></div>`

I try to update the self.data after an ajax call. I return the entire MVC model object and attempt to replace self.data like this :

```
self.data(updatedModel)
```

My expectation is that KO will take care of the update and no extra binding is needed. It works great for simple binding (ex. `Value: Data().Something`) but it doesn't work for complex binding (ex. `value: Data().BusinessUnits.SelectedGroup` ).

The controls that have complex binding are still bound to the old model, so KO doesn't know what to pass back next time I submit an ajax request.

Is this a limitation of KO, or I am not doing something properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `ko.mapping` plugin changes every property on `self.data` into an observable. During your update, you need to remap the updated data.

Since you didn't actually post your code, just unformatted snippets I can't help a whole bunch, but you should start by changing this line: `self.data(updatedModel)` to this:

`ko.mapping.fromJS(updatedModel, self.data);`

see the [Knockout.JS mapping documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)

Protip for stack overflow - include your full code, to the extent that it's possible. Also, if you can, make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Yes, that's what i did after some research. I realized that i didn't set self.data = ko.observable(). Making the change and then call self.data(newData) actually works well. Thanks for the input